# SQL Division of 4 Columns / Tuples (Select all ...)

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Goal:

I have the following relational schemas (primary key **bolded**):

- hospital(**hospital_id**)
- patient(**hospital_id**, **patient_id**, doctor_id)

  - foreign key (hospital_id, doctor_id) referneces doctor(hospital_id, doctor_id)
- staff(**hospital_id, eid,** name)

  - foreign key (hospital_id) referneces hospital
- doctor(**hospital_id, doctorid**)

  - foreign key (hospital_id, doctorid) references staff(hospital_id, eid)

I need to write the query

> "Create a view as(of) find the names of doctors who are taking care of *all* patient **in each(their) hospital**."

### What I have tried so far:

I'm thinking using [this formula](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division/):

```
SELECT * FROM R 
WHERE x not in ( SELECT x FROM (
(SELECT x , y FROM (select y from S ) as p cross join 
(select distinct x from R) as sp)
EXCEPT
(SELECT x , y FROM R) ) AS r );
```

with the tuple `x = (doctor_id, hospital_id) y = (patient_id, hospital_id)` by creating views:

```
create view doctor_patient as
  select (d.doctor_id, d.hospital_id), (p.patient_id, p.hospital_id)
  from doctor_employee d, patient p
  where d.doctor_id = p.doctor_id
  and d.hospital_id = p.hospital_id;

create view patient_hospital as
  select (p.patient_id, p.hospital_id)
  from patient p;
```

However, this obviously doesn't work with the error:

```
ERROR:  column "row" specified more than once

ERROR:  column "row" has pseudo-type record
```

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this task? Please let me know if this post needs any more specifications. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you return tuples in your views? They should select individual columns, e.g `CREATE VIEW doctor_patient AS SELECT d.hospital_id, d.doctor_id, p.patient_id FROM ...` (you have an equality check on `d.hospital_id = p.hospital_id`, so there is no need to select both columns in the view either).

Comment: Marth is right: remove those useless parentheses around the column names

Answer (score 0):

> Create a view as(of) find the names of doctors who are taking care of all patient in each(their) hospital.

I'll let you do the name part.  But you can get the doctor/hospital pairs using aggregation:

```
select hospital_id, doctor_id
from patient p
group by hospital_id, doctor_id
having count(distinct patient_id) = (select count(distinct p2.patient_id)
                                     from patient p2
                                     where p2.hospital_id = p.hospital_id and
                                           p2.doctor_id = p.doctor_id
                                    );
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think you have an extra ( after `from`. ^^;